# SSRS Switch function for conditional color

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

In my SSRS report i have a parameter "Year". I have only 3 year ( 2018,2019,2020). When the user select the 2020 or 2019 the color of the BAR for the selecting year changes automatically "Lime" but for the selection of 2018 the color remains "Silver"

```
 = Switch(
Fields!columnName.Value="Fluctuation Rate 2017", "Silver",
Fields!columnName.Value="Fluctuation Rate 2020", "Lime",
Fields!columnName.Value="Fluctuation Rate 2020 (Estimated)", "Yellow")
```

Bar chart colors are dynamically changes so current year bar is color lime

Comment: There is no question here, what is the actual issue?

Comment: What's the value of ColumnName for 2018? If there's more than one possible value, it can only pick one, otherwise the bar color should revert to the Automatic from the pallette.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Sorry for the incomplete statement. My question was how could I change the Series properties to make the Bar color dynamic?

Solved it via: = Switch(Fields!columnName.Value="Fluctuation Rate 2020", "Lime",
Fields!columnName.Value="Fluctuation Rate 2020 (Estimated)", "Yellow")

Comment: @HannoverFist: Solved it though not quite sure the how it is working cause I only used color switching for the 2020 year but it works automatically for 2019, 2018 year respectively.

Comment: @Hasan - if the columnName is not in the SWITCH, the chart would revert to the AUTO color selection from the selected Palette.